# Add empty group along x-axis to boxplot in ggplot (rephrased)

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

We are comparing two datasets (proteome and transcriptome) with matching groups, except for one group missing in the proteome data. As I plot the graphs underneath each other, they would be much easier to compare if the missing group would be represented in the plot.

For this, I need to find a way to plot an "empty" group along the x-axis in a boxplot of ggplot. I could not find a good example for this here or online (though similar questions have been asked) but I didnt get any solution to work for me as my groups are characters and I get the error: Error in factor("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"):
unused argument ("e")

## example data

I guess there would be a easier way creating this, but it works. Happy for new solution!

```
library(tidyverse)

   crete_exp_df <- function(gene_nr, sample_nr){
  df <- replicate(sample_nr, rnorm(gene_nr))
  df <- as.data.frame(df)
  colnames(df) <- paste("Sample", c(1:ncol(df)))
  rownames(df) <- paste("Gene", c(1:nrow(df)))
  return(df)
}

df1 <- crete_exp_df(5, 20)

# sample annotation

san <- data.frame(
  id = colnames(df1),
  group = sample(letters[1:4], 20, replace = TRUE))


df1$gene <- rownames(df1)

# long exp4 box ----
df_long <- df1 %>% pivot_longer(!gene, names_to = "id", values_to = "value")
df_long$group <- as.factor(san$group[match(df_long$id, san$id)])

# plot
df_long %>%
  filter(gene == "Gene 1") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

## expected result

[image]

Comment: Your code returns errors.

Comment: Set group as factor with levels, see linked post.

Comment: Solution doesnt work as I get the error: Error in factor("MB", "PM", "MC", "MM", "B", "S", "PMN") : 
  unused argument ("PMN")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an extra `level` when creating your `factor` column. So you could use `scale_x_discrete` with the `breaks` you want to show and make sure you use `drop=FALSE` to not remove the empty group like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# expression dataframe
crete_exp_df <- function(gene_nr, sample_nr){
  df <- replicate(sample_nr, rnorm(gene_nr))
  df <- as.data.frame(df)
  colnames(df) <- paste("Sample", c(1:ncol(df)))
  rownames(df) <- paste("Gene", c(1:nrow(df)))
  return(df)
}

df1 <- crete_exp_df(5, 20)

# sample annotation

san <- data.frame(
  id = colnames(df1),
  group = sample(1:4, 20, replace = TRUE))


df1$gene <- rownames(df1)

# long exp4 box ----
df_long <- df1 %>% pivot_longer(!gene, names_to = "id", values_to = "value")
df_long$group <- factor(san$group[match(df_long$id, san$id)], levels = 1:5)

# plot
df_long %>%
  filter(gene == "Gene 1") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete("group", breaks=factor(1:5), drop=FALSE)
```

[image]

If you want to have the same order as your expected output, you could change the order of the `breaks` by change the order of the `levels` of your `factor` like this:

```r
# long exp4 box ----
df_long <- df1 %>% pivot_longer(!gene, names_to = "id", values_to = "value")
df_long$group <- factor(san$group[match(df_long$id, san$id)], levels = c(1,2,3,5,4))

# plot
df_long %>%
  filter(gene == "Gene 1") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete("group", breaks=factor(1:5), drop=FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I will need to rephrase the question as my groups are characters and it seems not to be transfereable. I will redo the example code.

I get: Error in factor("MB", "PM", "MC", "MM", "B", "S", "PMN") [= my groups]: 
  unused argument ("PMN") [my data contains no S]